# Android auto CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to make [CollapsingToolbarLayout](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) to auto collapse or expand when user is scrolling?

I want to make it so when the user is scrolling and released his finger, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` will either collapse or expand based on the scroll direction.